# Linq contains()

Tags: database, linq, contains

I am implementing a search button, that pulls all products having the words a user will be entering in a textbox.

Say the user types :  Shoes.

I coded my linq to query the database to return all product containing the keyword in any of its columns as below

```
var products = from x in db.Products
where x.SupplierId == loggedInUser &&
( x.Status.ToString().Contains(searchCriteria) || 
x.SupplierCode.Contains(searchCriteria) ||
x.ProductId.ToString().Contains(searchCriteria) || 
x.Barcode.Contains(searchCriteria) ||
x.Description.Contains(searchCriteria) ||
x.ProposedActiveDate.ToString().Contains(searchCriteria) ||
x.VATRate.ToString() .Contains(searchCriteria) )
select x;
```

Problem ?

I do not get any product from the database(There is the product in the database).

What did I do wrong ?

Comment: Two things I can think it might be: SupplierId not matching loggedInUser, or case-sensitivity.

Answer (score 0):

I think you have the order wrong...

if the user had typed shoes, boots then you need to split the search terms "shoes" and "boots" and add them to a list<> and then do the following

```
SearchTermsList.Contains(x.Status.ToString()) ||   SearchTermsList.Contains(x.SupplierCode)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
  var searchCriteriaLowerCase = lowerCase.ToLower(); 
  var products = db.Products.Where(x=> x.SupplierId == loggedInUser &&
  x.Status.ToLower().ToString().Contains(searchCriteriaLowerCase) || 
  x.SupplierCode.ToLower().Contains(searchCriteriaLowerCase) ||
  x.ProductId.ToLower().ToString().Contains(searchCriteriaLowerCase) || 
  x.Barcode.ToLower().Contains(searchCriteriaLowerCase) ||
  x.Description.ToLower().Contains(searchCriteriaLowerCase) ||
  x.ProposedActiveDate.ToString().Contains(searchCriteria) ||
  x.VATRate.ToLower().ToString().Contains(searchCriteria) ).ToList();
```

This may work.

Answer (score -1):

I think you are not executing the query.

use like this.

```
var products = from x in db.Products
where x.SupplierId == loggedInUser &&
( x.Status.ToString().Contains(searchCriteria) || 
x.SupplierCode.Contains(searchCriteria) ||
x.ProductId.ToString().Contains(searchCriteria) || 
x.Barcode.Contains(searchCriteria) ||
x.Description.Contains(searchCriteria) ||
x.ProposedActiveDate.ToString().Contains(searchCriteria) ||
x.VATRate.ToString() .Contains(searchCriteria) )
.ToList();
```

Comment: what is the error you are getting? remove the ToString() method and try. I think .net ToString() will not work with db query.